# Dotnet test on .NET Core 1.1 in VSTS: No Test Discoverer is Registered

Tags: azure-devops, .net-core, mstest, vstest, dotnet-cli

I'm using VS 2017 with the new csproj in a .NET Standard class library, trying to test the library with a .NET Core 1.1 test project using MSTest testing framework with the `dotnet test` command. Running locally works perfectly fine; when I send the build to continuous integration, I get the error:

`No test discoverer is registered to perform discovery of test cases.`

How do I get this discoverer registered, and my tests running, in VSTS?

Comment: What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Nope, I think you just have to wait for M$ to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my build process on VSTS ([detailed on my blog here](http://mrpmorris.blogspot.co.uk/2017/06/running-dotnet-core-unit-tests-on.html))

1. Add a `dotnet restore` task.
2. Then a `dotnet build` task.
3. Add a `dotnet test` task with the arguments `--no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=tests-log.trx`
4. Add a `Publish test results` task with the following settings

[image]

1. `Test Result Format` = VSTest
2. `Test Result Files` = **/tests-log.trx
3. `Merge Test Results` = (checked)
4. In `Control Options` set `Run this task` to run even if a previous task has failed

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Create a new .Net Core test project with MSTest testing framework, there are MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework package references, which is importance
2. Add .NET Core (Preview) step (Command: restore)
3. Add .NET Core (Preview) step (Command: build)
4. Add .NET Core (Preview) step (Command: test)
5. Queue build with **Hosted VS2017** build agent.

Comment: This is exactly how my build was set up when getting this error

Comment: @Dagrooms Do you use Hosted VS2017 build agent? What's the detail build log? Can you reproduce that issue with a new project? You can share a simple project on the OneDrive.