# VSTS unit tests for .Net Core project: Tests not discovered

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a .Net core that builds successfully using VSTS. The issue I'm presenting is that ***Unit Tests aren't being discovered when building the project***. I know this is similar to **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528526/dotnet-test-on-net-core-1-1-in-vsts-no-test-discoverer-is-registered)** but I just wanted to bring up more details in case someone has a good idea seeing this description.

This a summary of the logs:

1. **`##[warning]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found`.**
2. **`##[section]Finishing: Test.`**

[image]
I'm concerned about the minimatch pattern used here. It seems is looking for a Tests folder and then any file that ends in `.csproj`

The default agent queue is **Hosted VS2017** as indicated by @starain-MSFT in previous **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528526/dotnet-test-on-net-core-1-1-in-vsts-no-test-discoverer-is-registered)** 
[image]

The solution structure is described in the next image, is pretty basic:

1. A .Net Core project with a model class.
2. A MS Unit Test Project (That contains a reference to the mentioned class).
3. A `[TestClass]` with a single `[TestMethod]` that pass the test.

[image]

Comment: So did you try other patterns that are in line with how your solution is structured / named?

Comment: Yes @Martin Ullrich,  I have tried other minimatch patterns and I discovered that this is the key of the solution. I will be posting the answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it resulted that my concern was the key factor to solve my issue.
I just made a little reverse engineer with an MVC project, the default minimatch pattern is different for this type of project, (`**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll !**\obj\**`)

You can learn more about minimatch **[here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/file-matching-patterns)**.

So I just wanted to look for a `.csproj` file that contains the word `Tests`, therefore I changed it to **`**/*Tests*.csproj`** instead of **`**/*Tests/*.csproj`**.

Now I'm able to see that my unit tests are being executed right away when there is a new build.[image]

I hope that my issue and resolution helps saving other people's time!

Comment: This helped me.  Thanks :-)